# Asking for Kick Member permission despite having given admin rights to Bot

Tags: discord, discord.py

So I am setting up a bot, and I am testing it out. A little function I have there is to kick, ban and unban users, set up in a cog, which goes as follows:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Moderator(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

#KICK command
@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(self, ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    ('About to kick')
    await member.kick(reason = reason)

@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=False)
async def kick(self, ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await ctx.send(f'You do not have permission to kick any member, {ctx.message.author.mention}!')

#BAN command
@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(self, ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.ban(reason = reason)
    await ctx.send(f'Banned {member.mention}')

@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=False)
async def ban(self, ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await ctx.send(f'You do not have permission to ban any member, {ctx.message.author.mention}!')

#UNBAN command
@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def unban(self, ctx, *, member):
    banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans()
    member_name, member_discriminator = member.split('#')

    for ban_entry in banned_users:
        user = ban_entry.user

        if (user.name, user.discriminator) == (member_name, member_discriminator):
            await ctx.guild.unban(user)
            await ctx.send(f'Unbanned {user.mention}')
            return

@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=False)
async def unban(self, ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await ctx.send(f'You do not have permission to unban any member, {ctx.message.author.mention}!')


#CLEAR MESSAGES
@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear(self, ctx, amount=2):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)

@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=False)
async def clear(self, ctx, amount=2):
    await ctx.send(f'You do not have permission to delete messages in this way, {ctx.message.author.mention}!')

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Moderator(bot))
```

***Now I have formatted the above code with some spaces so that it fits in one codeblock, so you might face indentation errors if you copy paste it elsewhere.***

Moving on, the bot itself has Administrator rights and separate Kicking and Banning rights too. It is also placed at the top of the role hierarchy, which is seen as:

[image: Role Hierarchy]

The name of my bot is JunkBot.

Now, whenever I, being the server owner, try using the command ***.kick @user***, it pops up the following error:

[image: Error upon using kick command]

The textual form of the error is:

```
Ignoring exception in command kick:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 777, in prepare
    if not await self.can_run(ctx):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1087, in can_run
    return await discord.utils.async_all(predicate(ctx) for predicate in predicates)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\utils.py", line 348, in async_all
    for elem in gen:
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1087, in <genexpr>
    return await discord.utils.async_all(predicate(ctx) for predicate in predicates)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1790, in predicate
    raise MissingPermissions(missing)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingPermissions: You are missing Kick Members permission(s) to run this command.
```

Similar errors are raised for the ban, unban and clear messages commands.

*Interesting part is, I, being the owner, get this error, but supposing another user, a friend of mine who does not have the kicking, banning or message managing role, runs their lines of codes perfectly, where she gets the message from the bot that she does not have permission to kick, ban or clear messages. The screenshot is enclosed.*

I don't know where I went wrong. Please help me debug it.

Comment: Your kick command works for me as written (as the owner of my own server)

Comment: Are you sure you used the exact same code as mine? Was your bot hierarchy somewhat similar to mine? Cam you share those details, like what permissions you gave to your bot and what roles did you as the owner have and the hierarchy of the roles?

Comment: My bot has admin permissions, and I copied and pasted your code (the `Moderator` class and the `kick` command) fixing the indents as necessary.

Comment: Just to clarify, you, the owner of the server (with all perms) cannot call this command. But, someone who doesn't have any perms, can use the commands? (I mean use as in the bot does actually do what its expected to do)

Comment: Right, I am the owner, with all the perms and I can't call this command, but if someone WITHOUT the perms calls this command, the bot responds the way it is supposed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in rewriting the functions. I'm assuming that you are hoping to make an [errorhandler](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#error-handling). However, this isn't the way to do so.

Instead of rewriting the functions with different `has_permissions` arguments, you will need to make a proper version of an error handler.

First, delete all the duplicate functions. These are the functions that require `False` on the `has_permissions` arguments.

Next, make a errorhandler function. You can make one for the Cog commands only, for all commands, or a specific command. If its for all commands, you will use the event [`on_command_error`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.on_command_error), (I suggest using it in the main file or as a listener). If it's for the Cog, then you will have to use [`cog_command_error`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Cog.cog_command_error). If it's for a specific command, you should make the [`Command.error`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Command.error) decorator.
I will be showing the Cog specific handler, but switching back and forth shouldn't take too long.

```py
# Indent into Cog level
async def cog_command_error(self, ctx, error):
    # Allows us to check for original exceptions raised and sent to CommandInvokeError.
    # If nothing is found. We keep the exception passed to on_command_error.
    error = getattr(error, 'original', error)
   
    if isinstance(error, commands.BotMissingPermissions): # Check if bot is missing permissions
        await ctx.send(f'I am missing these permissions to do this command:\n{self.lts(error.missing_perms)}')

    elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions): # Check if user is missing permissions
        await ctx.send(f'You are missing these permissions to do this command:\n{self.lts(error.missing_perms)}')


@staticmethod
def lts(list_: list): # Used to make reading the list of permissions easier.
    """List to string.
        For use in `self.on_command_error`"""
    return ', '.join([obj.name if isinstance(obj, discord.Role) else str(obj).replace('_', ' ') for obj in list_])
```

Here is the list of exceptions you can use in the handler: [`Exceptions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#exceptions)

FYI, the `lts` function I have isn't required for the handler. It's used to make the list of permissions readable in one string. You can always remove it or change it to your needs.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot! I am new to coding, and so I did not know about the error handling techniques. This Really helped my problem and this should work for the rest of the commands as well, thanks! Just for curiosity's sake, could you explain why those functions I wrote caused errors?

Comment: You were rewriting them so that only people who didn't have those permissions (meaning not you) could only use them. It's also only possible for one variable/function/class with the same name (throughout the global scope of the program)

Answer (score 2):

That is not how error handling works. You should check out the [error handling](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#error-handling) section of the docs for how to deal with missing permissions.

EDIT because people reminded me to give some more information

You shouldn't be handling errors through `has_permissions`. From what I can tell from your code, you are looking to send a message when the invoker doesn't have the permissions required to use the command. This can be achieved with an error handler. THe error handler will catch the `MissingPermissions` exception and do something based on that. Here is an example:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_command_error(self, ctx, error): #this is the event that catches errors
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions): #seeing if the error is the missing permissions error
        await ctx.send(f"You do not have the permission to do this, {ctx.author.mention}!")
```

This uses a **global** error handler, meaning that whenever an error is caught, this will catch it. However if you want an error handler for each command, all you have to change is the decorater and function name. EX:

```py
@kick.error
async def on_kick_error(self, ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(f"You do not have the permission to kick any member, {ctx.author.mention} ")
```

This one will only trigger on the `kick` command error, none of the others.

Comment: Precisely, I fail to see how the error handling documentation has anything to do with my issue. If you think this is resolvable via the error handling document, I request you to please guide me with the appropriate code.

Comment: @RakshitDeshmukh Actually, this does answer the question. But it isn't elaborate enough to explain why. This poster is on the right track

Comment: Could you then suggest a proper error handling included code as an  answer? It will be highly helpful if you contribute it.

Comment: To @Ay355 , I suggest elaborating your answer and explaining what you should do. Most people probably won't understand how your answer may answer the question or how to implement it if you don't explain anything.

Comment: Yep sorry about that, I was in the process of typing up the edit when your messages came. Hope I explained more this time.

Comment: No problem, just remember it in the future ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the valuable input! This helped me immensely in understanding error handling!